# Python, ¿Cómo contar palabras de un diccionario en un texto

Tags: python

Dado un texto, quiero utilizar un diccionario para contar la aparicion de determinadas palabras que hay en un texto. He estado mirando en la web todo son ejemplos de cómo crear un diccionario que almacene las palabras encontradas en el texto, pero no lo que yo quiero.

A modo de ejemplo, supongamos que quiero determinar cuantas veces aparecen las palabras: "casa", "coche" y "barco" en un texto. Yo haría

`base = {"casa":0,"coche":0,"barco":0}`

Luego miraría el texto y contaria. He visto que el modulo collections, tiene la funcion: "counter" que crea un diccionario con las palabras que ha encontrado y las veces que han aparecido, pero yo NO quiero tener luego que filtrar. Solo quiero contar las veces que aparecen las palabras de mi diccionario y que no me cambie el orden de esas palabras en el diccionario  ¿Alguna idea?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el enunciado indicas que no quieres buscar primero las palabras y filtrar luego. La solución del *"bucle con if"* sigue siendo un filtrado que procesa todas las palabras, algo que no es muy óptimo.

Habría una forma de hacer el proceso en un paso usando expresiones regulares:

```
import re
import OrderedDict

word_count = OrderedDict({"casa": 0, "coche": 0, "barco": 0})
words = re.compile('|'.join(word_count), re.IGNORECASE)

for word in words.finditer(texto):
    word_count[word.lower()] += 1
```

La variable *words* es un patrón creado a partir de la concatenación de las palabras a buscar (eg: `'casa|coche|barco'`). Con `re.IGNORECASE` nos busca tanto mayúsculas como minúsculas. Luego necesitaremos convertir a minúsculas (`word.lower()`) para hacer las cuentas.

En el bucle, usamos `.finditer()` mejor que `.findall()`. No necesitamos que nos busque la lista de todas las palabras. Con `finditer` buscará cada palabra según la necesitemos, lo que nos ahorrará mucha memoria si estamos analizando textos muy largos.

---

**Edición**: uso de un diccionario sin orden

En general, no tiene sentido hablar de ordenación de un diccionario. La implementación de los diccionarios ordena los índices según considere que sea más eficiente. Si importa el orden en el que se almacen los índices, lo recomendable sería usar un `OrderedDict`. Pero en este caso resulta más sencillo usar una tupla o lista con las palabras ordenadas:

```
import re

words = ("casa", "coche", "barco")
word_count = {word:0 for word in words}
pat = re.compile('|'.join(words), re.IGNORECASE)

for word in pat.finditer(texto):
    word_count[word.lower()] += 1

for word in words:
    print(f"{word}: {word_count[word]}")
```

Independiente de qué orden tengan los elementos del diccionario `word_count`, siempre se usa el orden de la tupla `words` para acceder a é.

Comment: Hola ChemaCortes, Muchas gracias por tu solución. De hecho sin saberlo, me has llevado a mi propósito original. Mi objetivo original era hacer una búsqueda de patrones "regex" usando un diccionario cuyas claves fueran patrones regex. Sin embargo, he leído por la red, que no es muy aconsejable usar un diccionario de regex, por que podría haber alguna palabra en el texto que se ajustara a más de un regex. Por eso he descartado esa posibilidad y he fijado las palabras a buscar.

Comment: El tema del orden está, en que según tengo entendido, cuando he encuentra una palabra del diccionario se actualiza el valor y la clave encontrada se pone en primer lugar. Sin embargo, no quiero que se cambie el orden aleatoriamente por que mi intención final es escribir en un fichero las veces que se ha encontrado cada palabra del diccionario. Si se altera el orden del diccionario, el fichero quedará corrompido de forma aleatoria.

Comment: @isg Cuando se busca un algoritmo de este tipo lo primordial es discriminar y clasificar los casos lo más rápido posible. Las regex funcionan muy bien para esta clasificación inicial, pero se necesitará más o menos trabajo posterior para obtener el resultado que necesites. En cuanto al orden de un diccionario, no cambia aleatoriamente. Pero no tiene mucho sentido hablar de ordenación cuando es voluntad del programador indicar el orden de acceso a los elementos. Voy a añadir un código que usa un diccionario sin ordenar para ilustrarlo.

Comment: Sí, tienes en cuanto a lo del regex para la clasificación inicial. Gracias por ayuda, efectivamente con tu estrategia se evita que se escriban los resultados en otro orden.